# How to write RewriteRule for login in a Wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, url-rewriting

In my wp multisite mysite.com, I want any login request to be sent to my custom login page at mysite.com/login. I found this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login/$ http://mysite.com/login/ [L]
```

It works, but it does not send the user back to the previous page after login. The previous page could be on mysite.com or mysite.com/subsite1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here´s the answer ;)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/login/$ http://mysite.com/login/ [L,QSA,NE]
```